# Is there a way to summon Dogmeat to you?

Tags: fallout-4

I've recently started playing Fallout 4, and I've acquired Dogmeat. Long story short, I told him to stay in a small building so I could down a few raiders quietly but I forgot about him and I can't find him. Is there a way to call Dogmeat back or do I have to retrace my steps until I'm reunited with him?

Comment: Funny, I've found my biggest hassle is making sure he stays away from me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can ask another companion to join you, at which point you should have an option to tell dogmeat to go back to one of your bases.

Answer (score 18):

If you are playing on the PC, you can move him to you. I had to do this once because he clipped in a wall and never came with me when I fast traveled away.

You can do it by following these steps.

Open up the Console by typing Tilde (~)

Type 'prid 0001d162'

Hit Return/Enter

Type 'moveto player'

Hit Return/Enter

Hit Tilde (~) again to close the console

Dogmeat will shoot to you like he is being magically summoned and be next to you!

Travel the Commonwealth with your Dogmeat

Comment: I like the answer with a 100% success rate

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC Thanks, I find that this is the only way to make a follower to come to you when you need them to.

Answer (score 10):

If you fast travel he will follow you again.

If you get another companion you will be asked where to send dogmeat.

Comment: If Dogmeat was told to "Stay", then I don't believe he'll fast travel with you.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that if you do part of the quest Reunions, he will wait at Fort Hagen, even if you use 'moveto' he will instantly run there.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! You haven't really laid it out, but it sounds like you're suggesting starting the quest to get Dogmeat to show up. That doesn't help if the player is past that quest, and is more involved than the currently accepted solution of getting another companion to follow you, even if they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

If you try all of these and they don’t work(especially the switching companions hint), dog meat automatically can be found again at red rocket if you didn’t assign him to a settlement.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Vault-Tec Population Management System console from the Vault-Tec Workshop DLC, which allows you to point companion positions on the radar and map. Or try to look at his last assigned settlement (which means where you sent him the last switch) or his first encounter spot, usually at the Red Rocket truck stop or Diamond City.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a command to summon him:

`1d162.moveto player`