# Fallout 4: That damn dogmeat

Tags: fallout-4

The pup everyone hates and loves. Dissapears and reapears. After using him to track Kelog, Valentine dismissed him and I have no idea where to. I looled at every settlement, used bells, used dog houses, waited at red rocket, even traced the path from the fort to red rocket, and nothing. Using xbox version so can't use some pc tactic I heard of. Can someone tell me what I can do? I don't wanna have to start over just to have my pup by my side. I got over 72 hours of grinding on this save, and not using mods so I can have achievements.

Comment: Possible duplidate of [Is there a way to summon Dogmeat to you?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245926/is-there-a-way-to-summon-dogmeat-to-you) See also [Where can I find Dogmeat after dismissing him to Sanctuary Hills?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242995/where-can-i-find-dogmeat-after-dismissing-him-to-sanctuary-hills)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an item called the "Overseer's Terminal" that you can build which places NPCs on the map.  But I do think that item is DLC only.

Comment: If it wasn't dlc oe mod, then videos would show people using it. Never even heard of it.

Comment: @LordNecrozome It is a DLC; the mechanimist one, I believe. I’ve seen videos of it.